# orders of columns in RadGrid

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik

I have a radgrid that contains a `MasterTable` and a `DetailTable`. The problem is that I can’t set the orders of the columns in the `Mastertable` and the `DetailTable`. 
Is it possible to set and save the orders myself t instead the default orders?

Answer (score 0):

I presume you are using `AutoGenerateColumns="True"`.

In order to specify the orders, you must specify each columns in the `<Columns>` tag and set `AutoGenerateColumns="False"`.

The order in which you specify the columns is the same used to display those columns.